# Celery Django not Registering Tasks, Module not found error in shell

Tags: python, django, registry, task, celery

I am trying to run a basic example from the Celery docs, but when I run 'from tasks import add' it gives me an error saying the 'module is not found'.

These are the files I have changed.

proj/proj/celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os

from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'proj.settings')

from django.conf import settings

app = Celery('proj')

# Using a string here means the worker will not have to
# pickle the object when using Windows.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

proj/proj/settings.py

```
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost//'

#: Only add pickle to this list if your broker is secured
#: from unwanted access (see userguide/security.html)
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'


INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'celerymod',
    'djcelery',
)
```

proj/proj/**init**.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from .celery import app as celery_app
```

proj/celerymod/tasks.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

from celery import shared_task


@shared_task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y


@shared_task
def mul(x, y):
    return x * y


@shared_task
def xsum(numbers):
    return sum(numbers)
```

Appreciate any suggestions. Thank you!

Answer (score -4, accepted):

If anyone else have the same issue. Do this in shell. myapp is the name of the application, in my case it is proj.

```
from myapp.tasks import add
```

Comment: And how it will help? Can you clarify more please.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem,

my tasks in the apps were not registered.

I could fix this by moving the import of celery.py into the settings.py instead of init.py

proj/proj/init.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
# is empty
```

proj/proj/settings.py

```
from .celery import app as celery_app
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost//'

#: Only add pickle to this list if your broker is secured
#: from unwanted access (see userguide/security.html)
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'


INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'celerymod',
    'djcelery',
)
```